# jQuery/Javascript: Defining a global variable within a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, global

I have this code:

```
        var one;
        $("#ma1").click(function() {
            var one = 1;
        })
        $("body").click(function() {
            $('#status').html("This is 'one': "+one);
        })
```

and when I click the body, it says: This is 'one': undefined. How can I define a global variable to be used in another function?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Remove the `var` from inside the function.

```
    $("#ma1").click(function() {
        one = 1;
    })
```

Comment: To expand upon why this works, when you used `var` inside the function, you created a new and separate local variable. By removing the `var`, you are essentially saying you want to look up the chain for a previously defined variable (in this case the global `one`).

Comment: Thanks for your help, Rocket. That saved me.

Answer (score 14):

If you want to make a global variable bind it to `window` object

```
window.one = 1;
```

Answer (score 12):

```
    var one;//define outside closure

    $("#ma1").click(function() {
        one = 1; //removed var 
    })
    $("body").click(function(e) {
        $('#status').html("This is 'one': "+one);
    })
```