# How to make global variable in a function?

Tags: javascript, html, json, blogger

I have code like this (http://jsfiddle.net/tb7E9/1/):

```
<script>
    function listEvents(json) {
        var feed = json.feed;
        for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            var entry = json.feed.entry[i];
            var posttitle = entry.title.$t;
            //Style
            if (i == 0) {
                x = "<span style='color:red'>Style 1 </span><p>" + posttitle + "</p>";
                p = "<span style='color:red'>Style 2 </span><h4>" + posttitle + "</h4><p>";
            }
            if (i == 1) {
                y = "<p>" + posttitle + "</p>";
                g = "<h4>" + posttitle + "</h4></p>";
            }
        }
        style1 = x + y; document.write(style1);
        style2 = p + g; document.write(style2);
    }
</script>
```

The second Script:

```
<script>
    //How to style1 is actived and style2 is disable here?
    document.write("<script src=\"http://www.allbloggertricks.com/feeds/posts/default/-/Tutorials?orderby=published&alt=json-in-script&callback=listEvents\"><\/script>");
</script>
```

I'd like to display only style (style1(normal text) or style2(bold text) as example in jsfiddle). It means if I choose style1 for display, then style2 is disable.

How can I change code in the second script to do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery/Javascript: Defining a global variable within a function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10389969/jquery-javascript-defining-a-global-variable-within-a-function)

Comment: Sorry. It's my mistake. I have remove jquery tag from my question. thanks

Comment: @Diodeus : I need help. It's not duplicated as above given question.

Comment: How do you "choose"? How do you know which style is chosen?

Comment: @Mathletics: yes. It's actual my problem need to solved. Because style1, style2 is in listEvents function. So, I don't know how to control it.

Comment: Nope, you lost me. I don't understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Mathletics: Maybe, using if(style1==true)...then...style1 is selected...If you can solve it, please give me the answer. If I know how to choose, then i may do not give the question here.

Comment: No one can solve this issue?

Comment: using something like window.style1? I don't see where the code is going, anyway

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct way to archive it.

```
function Y (){
  var window.X = *** ;

  console.print(window.X):
  console.print(X):

}
Y():

console.print(window.X):
```